# Hidden formatting symbols in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document in Persian language and there are many phrases in it like this: [image]

My problem is where the "و نشیب" connects to the "هایی".

At first it seems that there's a Zero width non-joiner character between them but actually when I tried to copy it, nothing copied.

I also copied all the phrase into the Notepad and I got this: "و نشیبهایی" As you see there's nothing between two foregoing words.

I turned the show/hide ¶ on in "Paragraph" group of "Home" tab to see if there is any hidden character and this is the result: [image]

Now, I wonder if there is any way to work with this character; e.g. replacing it with ZWNJ.

[A file with that problem](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8110877968/707598_ZWNJ_NWOB.doc.html) (also read below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complete replacement for my original Answer (the original text is below).

Your document marks words in green ("words that copy how you want") and red ("words that do not copy how you want").

Both types use a ZWNJ, e.g. to precede a Heh character that should only join to the left, not to the right.

The difference is that in the green words, the ZWNJ has been entered RTL, but in the red words, it has been entered LTR.

I do not know how you would normally enter a ZWNJ, but here, if I choose the "No-width Optional Break" from the Special Characters pane in the Symbol dialog, the ZWNJ is entered LTR (bad, in this case), whereas if I select character 0x200C from the table of characters in the Symbol dialog, it is entered RTL (good, in this case). In Word 2010, if I go into Word->File-Options->Customize Ribbon->Keyboard Shortcuts->Customize... and assign a keystroke to the No-Width Optional Break, pressing that keystroke when entering RTL text appears to insert the ZWNJ as RTL (good). You can assign that as follows:

- in the list of Categories, scroll down to "Common Symbols" and select
  it
- in the list of Common Symbols that is displayed, select "No-Width
  Optional Break"
- click in the "Press new Shortkey Key" box
- press the shortkey you want (I used ctrl-9 as an experiment)
- click Assign
- click Close

I don't know if that wil achieve everything you need, but I think it at least explains what is going on.

(I suspected it was something like that, but I had to save as .docx and look at the XML. The "green words" were encoded in a single Word "run" with "run property" RTL (a run is s sequence of characters that shares the same characteristics, so if you change text colour, there will be a new run). The red words were encoded as three runs: two RTL runs containing the text, and a non-RTL run containing the ZWNJ character.)

To change the LTR ZWNJs to RTL ones, you should be able to use the following VBA. (For those who know VBA, this is one of the occasions where you have to work with the Selection rather than Range, because AFAIK the only way to set a Run to RTL text is via the Selection object's RTLRun method):

```
Sub replace_LTR_NBZWs_with_RTL_ones()

ActiveDocument.Select
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = ChrW(8204)
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchKashida = False
  .MatchDiacritics = False
  .MatchAlefHamza = False
  .MatchControl = False
  .MatchByte = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  While .Execute
    Selection.RtlRun
  Wend
End With
End Sub
```

The original text of my answer follows...

It probably *is* a ZWNJ . If you select it, then click Insert->Symbol->More Symbols, the ZWNJ (0x200C) should be selected. It is the same as the character that Microsoft calls "No-Width Optional Break" in the "Special Characters" pane in the Symbol dialog.

As far as I know, NotePad ignores ZWNJ. I suspect you will have to replace the ZWNJ (if that is what it is) by a space (one selected, you ought to be able to press the space bar to do that) that will cause NotePad to display the correct character form.

Copying from one point in a Word document to another should preserve the ZWNJ, but is that what you are seeing?

Comment: As first part of your answer it seems that NWOB is same as ZWNJ in Word. I have both in my document and your saying was true about each one.
I tried to replace one with another and the result always was NWOB which Word displays it with a rectangle-like char.
Notepad doesn't ignore ZWNJ, you may insert it through right click > Insert unicode control character > ZWNJ.

Comment: Besides if we copy that text(with NWOB included) and paste it as unformated text, those words will completely connect to each other.
But if we copy that text(with ZWNJ included) and paste it as unformated text ZWNJ will remain between those words and I need this behavior.
I will include some part of my document in question for more clarity.

Comment: @Iman: Your sample document was very helpful. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Thank you @bibadia, I would wait for any suggestion from you and others

Comment: @Iman: I've now modifed my original answer.

Comment: I type ZWNJ through keyboard layout[*](http://persian-computing.org/en) by Shift+Space and with this method I think it is inserted as RTL since by this method I haven't such problem.
I've never used the "Special Character Window" method in this document and I don't know from where those LTR ZWNJs have produced, and what type of process maybe I did on text that cuased this problem.
Also my efforts to replacing through Word was useless.
Is it possible to replace these LTR ZWNJs through XML with RTL ones? If yes, how, please? I can extract XMLs from docx, but I'm unfamiliar with its structure.

Comment: I have added a VBA routine that should be able to do it. But please note that it will change all ZWNJs to RTL ones. I think that is probably what you need, but ideally it would at least be able to inspect the text direction of the surrounding text.

Comment: Yes! That did what I expected! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Iman: it was good to be able to make progress on this particular problem!

Answer (score 0):

Today I found another way to solve the problem. The trick is to replace the NWOB (with a character before and after) with itself then Word will do the trick...

- Find what: `(?)^o(?)`
- Replace with: `\1^o\2`
- Don't forget to put check mark beside `Use wildcards` in `More >>` pane

Then it will change LTR ZWNJs to that rectangle like mode and the RTL ones to what I was expected.